# ReactJS SVG icon load fails with svgr in order to change SVG fill dinamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack

I've been trying to use SVG in ReactJS for the past 2 hours but nothing seems to be working.

I'm using:

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",

"devDependencies": {
        "@svgr/webpack": "^6.0.0",
        "react-svg-loader": "^3.0.3",
```

Using create-react-app

I call the icon as:

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from '../../icons/logo.svg';
...
<Logo fill="white" />
```

And the error i get is:

```
./src/icons/logo.svg (./node_modules/@svgr/webpack/dist?-svgo,+titleProp,+ref!./src/icons/logo.svg)
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function.
```

If i use it in an "img" tag, the icon shows, but I need to dinamically change the fill of the SVG.
If there is a way on how i can load an svg and change the fill dinamically, please help and thank you.

Comment: could you check which node version u r using. SVGR is compatible with node 8+

Comment: another thing to try is remove react-svg-loader

Answer (score -1):

Try to import it as a variable, and then include that variable in an img tag in the src attribute as shown here.

```html
import Logo from '../../icons/logo.svg';

<img src={Logo} alt="logo" />
```

or add your svg as tag element and change the fill using css